# Modify Windows Installer COM Registration

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

My setup project in Visual Studio deploys a DLL that is set to register with COM. The installer takes care of the necessary registry settings, but there is one key I'd like to change: The InprocServer32 key on one of my classes. It normally contains 'mscoree.dll', but I need it to contain '[SystemFolder]mscoree.dll'. I tried to fix this several ways.

The first thing I tried was creating an MSI transform with an added entry to the Registry table and applying it as a post-build action. This routinely broke because my Component keys were not consistent across builds.

I then tried to create a registry entry with VS in the Registry window. This didn't work because the COM registration overwrote my registry key, not the other way around.

Then I went back to the MSI transform idea and added an entry in the Component table and made the registry key entry part of that component. This didn't work at all, and I don't know why.

So, does anyone know how to modify the COM registration in Windows Installer? Can you point out where I went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Installer - Registry keys being overwritten by COM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020576/visual-studio-installer-registry-keys-being-overwritten-by-com)

Comment: I can point out exactly where you have gone wrong: Using Visual Studio Deployment Projects.  The tool simply abstracts too much of Windows Installer and doesn't expose the underlying Windows Installer features that you need to manipulate.  I can tell you exactly how to modify COM registration data in Windows Installer, it just isn't possible to tell you how to do it in VDPROJ because it's hidden.

Comment: If you mean using Orca, I know how to do that, but it isn't automated - hence transforms. But transforms are having issues for me.

Comment: This is a very unusual requirement.  Lots of stuff stops working properly if the Windows system directory isn't high on the list of directories that get searched first.  Better fix the core problem.

Comment: No, I mean writing code to interop with the Windows Installer API to programatically create transforms.  Orca is just a tool and it's purpose is only to be able to look at the table data to understand what your code needs to do and validate that it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easily accomplished with Visual Studio Deployment projects. One of the many shortcomings that has contributed to Microsoft removing it from the next release of Visual Studio.

Check out other tools such as InstallShield Professional and Windows Installer XML.

Comment: I'm not looking for alternatives, I'm looking for a solution. Part of the reason for this is that my setup will be merged with a the setup for another program.

Comment: The problem is the only solution is an alternative.  And what do you mean by "Merged"?  Do you mean a nested / concurrent installation?  That is officially not supported by Microsoft anymore because of all the problems it caused. If you mean installed in series by a bootstrapper then it wouldn't matter because an MSI is an MSI.

Comment: If you really want to stick with VDPROJ you are going to have to write an script or program to be run as a postbuild event to programatically generate a transform.  Trust me, I've been through all this and by the time you figure out to do this and work through a bunch of other VDPROJ problems you could have just ported the project over to another tool and been done already.

Comment: Can you explain why creating a custom component for my transform doesn't work? Could I create a custom action and rely on it to be run after all my registration? There has to be a way to make it work in vdproj, even if it is complicated.

Comment: Look up my profile and email me.  I'll try a quick utility that will help you out before I leave for vacation.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you said mscoree, correct?   This technically means it's not actually COM ( native dll ) rather a COM Interop ( managed dll ). You could consider turning off the COM attibute in VDPROJ and use Regasm /regfile:test.reg foo.dll to generate a regfile.  Then you could author everything you see into registry components in VDPROJ.

Realize though that this stil won't author an elegant installer.